# How to I get the currently selected check value from CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox control with 6 checkboxes to choose from. I am trying to detect the following:

User checks the third index and changes the value from unchecked to checked.
Internal: Call an event - Grab the checked value of that third index.

That seems to suggest add a SelectedIndexChanged event. That doesn't tell me the user changed the value.

There's another: SelectedValueChanged.

I don't know if that tells me anything at all either, as the function is:

```
*_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

EventArgs is kind of useless to get this required information.

Again, I simply need to get the checked value of the item the user just selected. I'm not interested in gathering all selected items. Just the current one selected. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I confused this with a different control. You can use something like `chkList.Items[chkList.SelectedIndex]` where `chkList` is your CheckedListBox. e.g.: `Console.WriteLine(chkList.Items[chkList.SelectedIndex].ToString());`.

Comment: While ToString() gives the value, it doesn't tell me if the item is checked or not. And forgive me if I mistakened value for string value, whereas I meant the checked value. Still, knowing both is useful.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the displayed value (content) of the selected item you can use something like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex].ToStr‌​ing());
```

Or a shorter version:

```
Console.WriteLine(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

To determine if the selected item is checked or not, you can use something like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem));
```

This will be checking if the content of the selected item can be found among the checked items. That could lead to a wrong result if your CheckedListBox has duplicates. To avoid this, you might check for the index instead of the value, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Contains(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex));
```

**Edit:** An even better solution I just found, is to use the [`GetItemChecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Something like the following would work perfectly:

```
Console.WriteLine(checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex));
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Using Contains() can only work when the item is already selected. If I'm selecting a checkbox for the first time, Contains() seems to return false. If I do it again, it seems to return true.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually checking the checkbox *(not just selecting the item)*? You might need to have a look on the [`CheckOnClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkonclick(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Setting it to true would cause the items to be checked/unchecked by one click (when the item is selected).

Comment: You were a few seconds ahead of me on asking about such a property. The clicking and double clicking was confusing and probably to my users. The property made the difference. Thanks!